# FQL multiquery order

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a multiquery with 20 queries, everything works, but it returns the array in strange order:
query1,query11,query12...........query19, query 20, query3, query4 etc..

What I should do to get the queries ordered like query1,query2, query3 etc.

```
{"name": "query1",
  "fql_result_set": [{}]},
{"name": "query10",
  "fql_result_set": [{}]},
{"name": "query11", 
  "fql_result_set": [{}]},
```

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like it is ordered by string name, so to make it ordered as you wish you should rename your queries like so:
query01
query02
query03
...
query10
query11
query12

hope this helps

Comment: I have a similar situation: query01, query02, query03. The response I get is in a arbitrary order: query01, query03 and then query02. This makes my life complicated as I need to get response[1] (I expect query02 not query03!) any ideas?